# Opening and closing dropdown in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

When I click on buttons nothing is happening. I am trying to make them open and close. How can I solve this?werrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr

HTML

```
    <div class="sidenav">
    <img src="assets/images/placeholder-logo.svg">

    <li ng-repeat="item in data" ng-if="dataLoaded">
        <button class="dropdown-btn">{{item.streamName}}
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-container">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="element in item.apps">
                    <button class="dropdown-btn">{{element.appName}}
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down" ng-if="element.sheets.length"></i>
                    </button>
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="sheet in element.sheets">
                            <button class="dropdown-btn">{{sheet.sheetName}}
                            </button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
            var i;

            for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
            dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
                if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
                dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
                }
            });
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working, but it will hide the content area only after the second click on the button because the initial value `dropdownContent.style.display` is empty string, but you check if it's equals to "block".

So the first click on the button set the content area to `display: block`.

You need to change the check to `dropdownContent.style.display === ""`

```
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
    dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block" || dropdownContent.style.display === "") {
            dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```